# Database Design Approach

Tags: database, database-design, yii

I have to design a database for 3 types of user profiles on a website . Their are various fields for each user in the profile which they may or may not fill . Example : Fields for contact numbers (3 in number) , fields for services offered (10 in number) , accreditations (6) . The user can fill no field or all fields . What is a better approach :

1) Make fixed number of columns such as :contactnumber1 , contactnumber2 , contactnumber3 . Allow Blank entries for user .

2) Or make a separate table contact numbers which maps each entry to a user id . This would mean multiple entries for the same user id . This would ensure that no column is blank . However for displaying the information I would have to traverse multiple 'indexed' tables (~8-9) at the same time , come back with results and publish the same .

In the first approach I have to go to fewer number of tables but their is a good chance of many users leaving their records blank .

I am building in the PHP-YII framework . What is best approach considering performance and scalability as a criteria ?

Or is their another way to do this ?

Comment: Follow the second option. Then you could create a view on your data, where you pull together the separate tables (within the db) and query just that view.

Comment: 1) Tends to create horrific queries - instead of querying one column, you have to query 10. Then, in three months time, you discover you made a copy-and-paste error and were querying `Service3` twice and not querying `Service4` at all...

Comment: Okay another question , the users are going to have multiple types of the same data type . Example : Work contact number and Residential contact number . Should I split it into two tables or do it with one table using a type column to identify the contact number type ?

Comment: I'd go for a single table. Again, not knowing what type of queries you'll be writing, I can only go by gut feeling, but if someone needs to search by phone number, would you want to search one column in one table, or 1 column in "n" tables, where "n" is the number of distinct types. Assuming Work and Residential numbers are "identical" except for this very type distinction (not different validation rules, etc)

Comment: This data is not for searching , just for display purpose . Numbers would be choosen as varchar and same validation rules will apply , essentially making them the same 'data' type . They would translate differently only on the front end , driven by business logic . I think I would go with one table .So the operations are going to be update the record , create a new record and select a new record for display .